# twitteR Error when authorizing token

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to register an OAuth token and I am running into an error that doesn't seem to be explained anywhere I can find.

```
require("ROAuth")
require("twitteR")

requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
```

Here is where I would plug in my consumer key and consumer secret which I obtained properly.

```
consumer_key <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
consumer_secret <- "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
```

This is the first attempt:

```
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumer_key, consumerSecret = consumer_secret, requestURL = requestURL, 
                             accessURL = accessURL, authURL = authURL)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object '.setDummyField' not found
```

Other posts suggested I use the following:

```
getTwitterOAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
```

But I get the same error. I can't seem to find the error reproduced anywhere else which is making me suspect it has nothing to do with the `twitteR` or `ROAuth` packages. I'm new to these so any advice on how to fix the error is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is your literal code: in the first code block you assign the variable `requestURL`, but when you call `OAuthFactory$new` you use `requestURL = reqURL`. I suspect this is not the problem because if it was, the error should be: `Error in callSuper(...) : object 'requestURL' not found`, but you should provide functional code.

Comment: Yeah thats my fault, I had two different scripts going (two different attempts) and there seemed to be cross-contamination at one point. I edited out the issue

Comment: You might try the getTwitterOAuth() function, it has a habit of making a lot of these problems go away due to fewer moving parts

Comment: You can see with the last line of code that I tried that also, but I may have been using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The following sequence of commands solved the problem:

```
consumerKey <- ...
consumerSecret <- ...
twitCred <- getTwitterOAuth(consumer_key= consumerKey, consumer_secret=consumerSecret)
searchTwitter()
```

Notice I didn't use `registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)`. I think if you wanna save and later load `twitCred` you have to use `registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)` after loading.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In the new versions of the package, one should use `setup_twitter_oauth` instead of `getTwitterOAuth`.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the question:

> Other posts suggested I use the following:
>
> ```
> getTwitterOAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
> ```
>
> But I get the same error.

So pbahr's answer wouldn't have helped I take it?

I was getting the same issue using both OAuthFactory$new and getTwitterOAuth but fixed it when I upgraded my R version from 3.0.0 to 3.0.2

I'm not sure if the version is the main cause of the issue but upgrading it worked for me.